# Check spinners to prevent them selecting the same item

Tags: android, spinner

I was planning to do checking on spinners to make sure they are not selecting the same items.

there goes my code

```
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/StudentName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please select Course and Grade"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerC1"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" 
            android:entries="@array/course"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerG1"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:entries="@array/grade" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerC2"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" 
            android:entries="@array/course"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerG2"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" 
            android:entries="@array/grade"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerC3"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:entries="@array/course" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerG3"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" 
            android:entries="@array/grade"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerC4"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" 
            android:entries="@array/course"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerG4"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" 
            android:entries="@array/grade"/>
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
          android:weightSum="1"
        >

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/SpinnerC5"
         android:layout_width="221dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_weight="0.7"
         android:entries="@array/course"/>

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/SpinnerG5"
         android:layout_width="83dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_weight="0.3"
         android:entries="@array/grade"/>

        </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/SpinnerC6"
             android:layout_width="221dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="0.7" 
             android:entries="@array/course"/>

         <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/SpinnerG6"
             android:layout_width="83dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="0.3" 
             android:entries="@array/grade"/>

     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Calculate GPA" 
             android:onClick="calculateGPA" />


     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then my whole java code of this page will be

```
 package com.example.gpapredict;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Selection extends ActionBarActivity {
    String stuName,stuId, gpaScore, defCourse,gradeA,gradeB,gradeC,gradeD,gradeF,gradeG;
    ArrayList<String> check;
    double cor,score,gpa=999;
    TextView tvName;
    Intent i2;
    Spinner SpinnerC1, SpinnerC2, SpinnerC3, SpinnerC4, SpinnerC5, SpinnerC6, SpinnerG1, SpinnerG2, SpinnerG3, SpinnerG4, SpinnerG5, SpinnerG6;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);
        stuName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        stuId = getIntent().getStringExtra("stuId");
        tvName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.StudentName);
        tvName.setText("Hi," + stuName);
    }

    public void calculateGPA(View v){
        //retrieve data from spinners
        SpinnerC1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerC1);
        SpinnerC2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerC2);
        SpinnerC3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerC3);
        SpinnerC4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerC4);
        SpinnerC5 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerC5);
        SpinnerC6 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerC6);
        SpinnerG1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerG1);
        SpinnerG2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerG2);
        SpinnerG3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerG3);
        SpinnerG4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerG4);
        SpinnerG5 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerG5);
        SpinnerG6 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerG6);

        //save the data into string type
        String[] course = new String[6];
        String[] grade = new String[6];
        course[0] = SpinnerC1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        course[1] = SpinnerC2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        course[2] = SpinnerC3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        course[3] = SpinnerC4.getSelectedItem().toString();
        course[4] = SpinnerC5.getSelectedItem().toString();
        course[5] = SpinnerC6.getSelectedItem().toString();
        grade[0] = SpinnerG1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        grade[1] = SpinnerG2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        grade[2] = SpinnerG3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        grade[3] = SpinnerG4.getSelectedItem().toString();
        grade[4] = SpinnerG5.getSelectedItem().toString();
        grade[5] = SpinnerG6.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //check for no same course
        defCourse = "Select Course";
        check = new ArrayList<String>();
        check.add(course[0]);

        for (String checkCourse:check ){    
            for (int c=1;c<6;c++){  
            if (checkCourse.equals(course[1])){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Proceed : Same course is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else if(course[c].equals(defCourse)) {
                    continue;
                }else {
                    check.add(course[c]);
                    break;
                }
            }                           
        }




        //calculate score
        gradeA="A";
        gradeB="B";
        gradeC="C";
        gradeD="D";
        gradeF="F";
        gradeG="G";
        //initialize value
        score = 0.0;
        cor=0.0;
        for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
            if(grade[i].equals(gradeA)){
                score = score + 4.0;
                cor++;
            }else 
            if (grade[i].equals(gradeB)){
                score = score + 3.0;
                cor++;
            }else
            if (grade[i].equals(gradeC)){
                score = score + 2.0;
                cor++;
            }else
            if (grade[i].equals(gradeD)){
                score = score + 1.0;
                cor++;
            }else
            if (grade[i].equals(gradeF)){
                score = score+0.0;
                cor++;
            }else{
                score = score +0.0; 
            }       
        }
        if (cor == 0.0){
            cor++;
        }
        gpa = score/cor;
        //set precision to 2 decimal places
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        gpaScore = String.valueOf(dec.format(gpa));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "okay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        i2 = new Intent(Selection.this,Result.class);
        i2.putExtra("stuName",stuName);
        i2.putExtra("stuId",stuId);
        i2.putExtra("courseArray", course);
        i2.putExtra("gradeArray", grade);
        i2.putExtra("gpa", gpaScore);
        startActivity(i2);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.selection, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

due to the limit of link that I can post, Ill show my interface and the error message at the other image.

Now my application able to show user error when comparing the other spinners' value with the first spinner's value. because my application find out that the first and the second spinner are selecting the same course. it is as shown in the image.

[Result that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwzqR.png)

if the second spinner's value is different from the first one but same with the third spinner's value, the application allow to proceed to next page. which is not what i want. I want my application to make sure that user do not select the same subject from the spinners.

this image shows the result of user select the same course at the 2nd spinner and the third spinner. which i do not want it to be.

[Result of 2nd spinner and third spinner have the same value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSyyL.png)

once again your help is much appreciated, if my explaination is still not clear enough, I wailing to explain even more details.

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion, on clicking the proceed button, you should have an arraylist of selected values of `spinners` and then check if arraylist has duplicate values. Try following code :

```
 //check for no same course
    defCourse = "Select Course";
    ArrayList check = new ArrayList<String>();
    check.add(defCourse);

        for (int c=0;c<6;c++){  
            if (!check.contains(course[c])) {
                check.add(course[c]);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Proceed : Same course is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but then i must select 6 course already. What if i want my application proceed to next activity even though user only choose three subjects?

Answer (score 0):

Well i found my solution

```
// check for no same course
        defCourse = "Select course";
        check = new ArrayList<String>();
        check.add(course[0]);

        for (int c = 1; c < 6; c++) {
            if (check.contains(course[c])) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Cannot Proceed : Same course is selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } else if (course[c].equals(defCourse)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                check.add(course[c]);
            }
        }
```

thank you for your help :)